# Unable to fetch Json file from separate project in Eclipse

Tags: java, json, eclipse, inputstream

I have a java application that I wants to load *JSON* into. The *API* method I'm invoking takes a `InputReader` so I tried the following code below:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Assets.class.getClassLoader();
new InputStreamReader(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("data/clientJson.json")));
```

The file is in the `Assets` package under the '*data*' folder and yet the `InputStreamReader` always throws an exception stating that the input is `Null`.

If I move the file next to the class and change the `Classloader` to reference the same class it works, but not with the `Assets` class.

I've tried every permutation of the name path as well to no avail.

Comment: You can't have a fully qualified class name that is identical to a package name--it causes issues at runtime and hopefully compile-time. Why would you have to move the file? How does the separate project in the title involved?

Comment: The project was created using the PlayN framework. It uses a separate package for the Shared, Assets, Android, Java, Html5 etc. builds. The framework comes with built in methods for loading PlayN related assets, but no built-in JSON support.

Comment: You might want to change "Package" into "Project" (if I understand you correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your other Eclipse project is imported and if the data/ folder is under the src/ folder (or otherwise marked in the other project as a classpath resource), then it will work. I think you first need to verify if the Eclipse import/export relationship and the other folders classpath is correct.

[image: Sample 2 Project Setup in Eclipse]

If you go to the asset (A in my example) project's properties the resources/ folder must be under "Order and Export". You can add it under "Libraries" as "Class path folder". And the Assets project must be "required projects on the build path". Note the "classpath folder" icon on A/src/main/resources.

Comment: The 'Qualifed Name' that Eclipse is giving me is: /assets/src/main/resources/assets/data/clientJson.json.

Comment: This looks like you need to load `assets/data/clientJson.json`

Comment: Still throws the Null Pointer exception. Could there be some project setting in Eclipse I need to set?

Comment: The screenshot clarified things and I'm up and running.

Comment: Thanks @ChargerIIC for the feedback. Can you check my above comment to your question, I think using the term "Package" when you mean "Eclipse Project" is rather missleading (as you can see in the first comment to your question).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
new InputStreamReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("data/clientJson.json"));
```

EDIT:

static URL  from **http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html**

```
       getSystemResource(String name)
      //Find a resource of the specified name from the search path used to load classes.
```

BTW I always use .getInputStream(); ex:

```
  BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(object.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: getResource returns a URI object, which the InputStreamReader won't accept as a constructor argument. Is there a way to get InputStreamReader to take the URI?